# Streaming a file in Liferay Portlet

Tags: spring-mvc, streaming, liferay, portlet

I have written downloading a file in a simple manner:

```
@ResourceMapping(value = "content")
public void download(ResourceRequest request, ResourceResponse response) {
//...
SerializableInputStream serializableInputStream = someService.getSerializableInputStream(id_of_some_file);

response.addProperty(HttpHeaders.CACHE_CONTROL, "max-age=3600, must-revalidate");
response.setContentType(contentType);
response.addProperty(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, contentType);
response.addProperty(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename*=UTF-8''"
    + URLEncoder.encode(fileName, "UTF-8"));

OutputStream outputStream = response.getPortletOutputStream();
byte[] parcel = new byte[4096];

while (serializableInputStream.read(parcel) > 0)
    outputStream.write(parcel);

outputStream.flush();
serializableInputStream.close();
outputStream.close();
//...
}
```

The `SerializableInputStream` is described [here - JavaDocs](http://openhms.sourceforge.net/rmiio/apidocs/com/healthmarketscience/rmiio/SerializableInputStream.html). It allows an InputStream to be serialized and, for instance, passed over remoting.

I read from input and write it to the output, not all bytes at once. But unfortunately the portlet isn't "streaming" the contents - the file (e.g. an image) is sent to the browser only after reading the entire input stream - this is how it looks like. I see the file being read from the database (from live logs), but I don't see any "growing" image on the screen.

What am I doing wrong? Is it possible to really stream a file in Liferay 6.0.6 and Spring Portlet MVC?

Comment: ServletContainer has it's own buffer, maybe you want to put the outputStream.flush() inside the while loop to make it flush it regularly. Also make sure the browser can actually render that kind of image partially - maybe this is just how the browser behaves (loads image completely before rendering it).

Comment: I tried flushing, same effect. The image is BMP, so it could be rendered partially..

Answer (score 0):

Where are you doing this? I fear that you're doing this instead of rendering your portlet's HTML (e.g. render phase). Typically the portlet content is embedded in an HTML page, thus you need the resource phase, which (roughly) behaves like a servlet.

Also, the code you give does not match the actual question you ask: You use a comment `//read from input stream (file), write file to os` and ask what to do differently in order to not have the full content in memory.

As the comment does not have anything in memory and you could loop through reading from the input file while writing to the output stream: What's the underlying question? Do you have problems with implementing download-streaming in a portal environment or difficulties (i.e. using too much memory) reading from a file while writing to a stream?

**Edit**: Thanks for clarifying. Have you tried to flush the stream earlier? You can do that whenever you want - e.g. every loop (though that might be a bit too much). Also, keep in mind that the browser as well as the file itself must handle it in a way that you expect: If an image is not encoded "incrementally" a browser might not show it that way.

Have you tried this with huge files as well? It might be that the automatic flushing is just not triggered because your files are too small for it to be triggered...

Also, I think that `filename*=UTF-8''` looks strange. Might be valid encoding, but I've never seen this

Comment: I have updated the question, I hope it will be clearer what I am doing and what I need.

Comment: I will try to flush more often.. maybe it'll work. I've tried to stream a large bitmap before, and the streaming was a bit choking ... I couldn't tell if it was or wasn't working..